# What going to happen to Dulche De Leche during baking?

Tags: baking, cake, boiling, filling, dulce-de-leche

Dulche De Leche is condensed milk that boiled already. But what if put it in something that going to be boiled or baked. How it's going to be, how it's going to taste like? Do people do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will taste like dulce de leche.  It's already caramelized, so it's not going to change in most recipes.  If you cook it on high heat for long enough in a baking recipe, it will become a darker caramel, but that's it.

It will become more liquid at high heat, so you want to make sure you cook it "contained", like in an empanada or pie crust.  Otherwise it might drip onto the floor of the oven and burn.

Comment: I think the not changing is more because of the amount of heat, not because it's already caramelized. If you put condensed milk in a pie and bake it, there's not going to be enough heat over time to caramelize it. (On the other hand, if you did actually manage to subject it to enough heat that it'd have turned condensed milk to dulce de leche, you might actually burn the caramel.)

Comment: I haven't looked into how much baking heat would be required to turn condensed milk into caramel in a baked dish.  It should be possible; flan depends on caramelizing the sugar on the bottom of the mold.

Comment: I believe every flan recipe I've seen has caramelized sugar syrup. In any case, the reason dulce de leche ends up caramelized is that it's basically held at boiling temperature for something like 1-3 hours. That's way longer at that temperature than basically anything baked.

Comment: You don't like your biscotti in carbon black?

Comment: don't forget about adding water when making dulce de leche, especially if you have a popcorn ceiling. don't ask.